# Print text if cells in a row contain certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve data within a row and compare if the cells contain certain text. If they do then print the information into the column next to it. I have provided a picture down below of my spreadsheet. I am trying to get compare and get the conflicts within that row. I have tried possibly making an array and adding to it each time the row has a conflict, but I cant seem to get it right. It would print out the conflict even if the cell is blank. Or wouldn't print anything even if there is a conflict visible. Basically I am trying to see if the cell contains "Conflict" since the text after it is too specific to detect in general.If it contains that value, then add it to the array. Then in the end, print the array out for that row.

Excel Sheet:

[image: sheet image]

Comment: `set foundCell = range().find("conflict")` and `if not foundCell is nothing then` write to `cells(foundCell.row,appropriateColumn)`?

Comment: A lot of your code looks like it could be looped, saving many lines of code.  You may want to visit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and if it's OK with because the code is not using an array...

[image]

and if the image above is the kind of your situation, then maybe you want to have a look the sub below to help you get started.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim col As Long:
Dim c As Range: Dim FirstAddress As String
Set rg = Range("A1:F5") 'range of data - change as needed
col = 8 'column of the expected result - change as needed

'get the first occurence of the found cell
Set c = rg.Find("xxx", lookat:=xlPart, _
    after:=rg(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count))
FirstAddress = c.Address 'put the first found cell address into FirstAddress variable

    Do 'loop as long as the next found cell address <> FirstAddress
        With Cells(c.Row, col) 'the cell where the result will be put
            If .Value = "" Then .Value = c.Value _
                Else .Value = .Value & ", " & c.Value
        End With
        Set c = rg.FindNext(c)
    Loop While c.Address <> FirstAddress
    
End Sub
```

It use the Find-FindNext method then write (and concatenate if more than one) the result into column 8 with the row of the found cell's value.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! Yes, according to the short video that's exactly what I am trying to do. And no worries, I don't specifically have to use an array, I thought that's what I had to do in order to concatenate the strings into one cell.